# How to disable the <ul> tag using ng-class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-class

I have a div structure like follows,

```
<ul data-ng-class="{'dropDownDisabled': (items.results && items.results.disabled) }">
    <li

        class="dropdown-item org-labels"> {{items.name}}</li>

    <span   data-ng-repeat="result in items.results.contextValues.rows" t>
        <li class="dropdown-item"
            data-ng-click="filter.onResultClick(items, result, filter)"
            data-ng-class="{'dropdown-item-selected' : result[0] === (ctrl.isEmpty(filter.selectedValue) ? '-1' : filter.selectedValue.code)}"
        >
            {{result[1]}}
        </li>
   </span>
</ul>
```

I am trying to apply 'disable' class to `<ul>` tag but due to the following class

```
.dropDownDisabled:hover {
    pointer-events: all !important; 
    background-color: #bbb !important;
 }

.dropDownDisabled:hover {
    pointer-events: all !important; 
    background-color: #bbb !important;
 }
```

But on hover on li,there is a background color getting applied due to the following class,

```
 .annual-comp-container .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover {
     background-color: #f7f7f7;
 }
```

Due to which,when the disable condition is true, the class 'dropdownDisable' is getting applied but due to the above class '.dropdown-item:hover' when I hover the background color is applied.What I want is when the ul is disable '.annual-comp-container .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover' should not apply.

Comment: Can you provide the rendered HTML? I suspect the `span` tag could be the issue.

Comment: Apart from the possible invalid html with having `span` as a child of `ul` you also have a naming issue in your angular/html you have the class: **dropDownDisabled** in your CSS you have the class: *dropdownDisable* , these are NOT the same, the spelling is different and case matters.

Comment: @John P yes I changed it

Comment: Why are you using `:hover` on `disabled` state?

Comment: @Awais,it is kept for non disable state but getting applied when disabled.Thats the problem.

Comment: Can you share us the screenshot of this code in inspector? or add other class with `.dropDownDisabled` like `.dropDownDisabled.disabled` and style it as you want

Comment: As above, if you can provide the rendered HTML it would help. This JSFiddle shows the colour does apply as expected with that CSS https://jsfiddle.net/bzpsgjn2/2/